changing the banner color of "[product] has been added to your cart."
How do I change the color of the banner that displays the "[product] has been added to your cart." Currently the color is green.
Thank you for any help offered!
Is

You'll have to ask the support team for your theme or for the plugin you're using for e-commerce.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Assuming that you are using WooCommerce, add that you want to change the color on the single product page, you can add in your css:
.single-product .woocommerce-message { background-color: #000; color: #FFF; border: none; }
